# Format a value inside interpolated string in typescript

Tags: typescript

I need to format a string in Typescript like this:

```
`${date.getHours()}:${date.getMinutes()}:${date.getSeconds()}`
```

but I get this for example: `20:9:31`

How can I add format inside interpolated string and get `20:09:31`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var n = 9;
var fNumber= ("0" + n).slice(-2); //fNumber = 09
```

So this should work:

```
`${date.getHours()}:${("0" + date.getMinutes()).slice(-2)}:${date.getSeconds()}`
```